# Sharepoint Edit or New item meta data page Title shows up twice

Tags: sharepoint, content-type

current setup: 
1. Parent content type (PCT1) has 5 columns (including Title column)
2. Child content type (CCT1-A) inherites from PCT1 and adds 5 more columns (but child ct also comes with it's own Title column).
3. Now I associates Child control type to a document library.
4. I see two titles in the edit item or new item page
5. If i disable (hide) any one of the Title column (either in parent or child ct. NOT hiding from both CT) then both titles dissappears from edit or new page
6. What are my solution?
7. I must have the Title column but it seems each CT is bringing it's own Title

Please suggest.

Comment: First of all, welcome to stackoverflow. Second... you may have a better chance getting a useful answer if you specify the version of SharePoint you are using and if you format your text to a more readable format.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply exclude CCT1-A.Title column from your child content type, if you need only one title and columns CCT1-A.Title and PCT1.Title are same type.

If titles are different types, and you want to save their names, simpliest workaround is to replace these 2 old with new **3** content types:

1. **First** has 4 columns from your PCT1 NOT including "Title"
2. **Second** inherits from the First, and has extra column "Title"
3. **The last** one inherits from First too, and has 5 extra columns from CCT1-A, including "Title"

So, second is equivalent to your old PCT1.

Third is equivalent to your CCT1-A, without PCT1.Title column

First is internal, "base" content type.

Details on creating SharePoint 2010 content types you can find on MSDN, please, follow link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543822(office.14).aspx

Hope it helps!